# how to store data into temporary instead of database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to insert my data into temporary in mvc
I dont want to store data directly into database
For an example, as u visit to a mall and buy 5-6 things, so first it wont store all data in database, instead it stores into somewhere in application.
Like this what logic may i use to make this type of site

`public ActionResult Education_Detail(Education objEducation)
        {
            sp.Reg_Can_Education(ref objEducation);
            objEducation.CorColl = (CourseCollection)TempData["objCourseColl"];
            TempData["objCourseColl"] = objEducation.CorColl;`

```
        for (int item = 0; item < objEducation.CorColl.Count; item++)
        {
            if (objEducation.CorColl.Item(item).CourseId.ToString() == objEducation.objCourse.CourseId)
            {
                objEducation.objCourse.CourseNm = objEducation.CorColl.Item(item).CourseNm.ToString();
            }
            if (objEducation.objCourse.CourseNm != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in cookie or session and when user check out store it to database.